# Get actual error from ol.source.WMTS.optionsFromCapabilities

Tags: openlayers, wmts

I am using the method [ol.source.WMTS.optionsFromCapabilities](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_source_WMTS.html#.optionsFromCapabilities) to create a WMTS layer and when I am trying to use a projection that does not exist in OpenLayers it throws an error.

> Please note that in my case the projection is not available up front.

Unfortunately, the nature of the error is very general. When using the minified version I get:

> Cannot read property 'wb' of null

along with the stack trace, which is translated to the following when using the debug version:

> Cannot read property getCode() of null

Is there a way to get the actual error and not one in just plain text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, OpenLayers only checks for and gives meaningful messages for a few specific errors https://openlayers.org/en/latest/doc/errors/ and trying to use a projection which hasn't been defined and registered in proj4 isn't one of those.

If you are using a source with unknown projections you could try obtaining the projection from the parser

```
  var parser = new WMTSCapabilities();
  fetch(url).then(function(response) {
    return response.text();
  }).then(function(text) {
    var result = parser.read(text);
    console.log(result.Contents.TileMatrixSet[0].SupportedCRS);
```

then dynamically load the projection definition as in the OpenLayers example https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/reprojection-by-code.html before creating your layer